# How can I mute my laptop for an hour

Tags: windows-10, mute

I get into meetings and mute my laptop. But forget to unmute it when I come out. This leads me to miss the notifications from my outlook.

Is there a way to mute the laptop for say 1 hour. It should automatically unmute after an hour. I have seen the answers about nirCMD. But this is not scheduled task. It should be on demand.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What have you tried so far? :)

Comment: There are some [tools](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/automatically-adjust-volume-by-time-with-volume-concierge/). Setting the schedule just before your meetings is also an on-demand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nircmd` combined with `timeout` to achieve that.

For example, to mute for 5 seconds, run this from your cmd:

```
nircmd mutesysvolume 2 && timeout /t 5 && nircmd mutesysvolume 0
```

You can save it in a batch (`.bat`) file with a constant value and create a shortcut somewhere.

Note that `timeout /t` accepts a number of seconds, so you would want to use `3600`.

Comment: Or save it as a `.bat` file.

Comment: Was just editing the question to add it :)

Comment: excellent. also worth saying a number of commands have built in timers, notably `shutdown` e.g. `shutdown -s -t 600` will shut down the pc in 10 minutes.

Comment: Simple, free and effective. Added bonus, I have the option to unmute earlier than 1 hour.

Answer (score 1):

I use a program called [Macro Express](https://www.macros.com/) (not free) but there are other similar programmatic style packages that accomplish similar tasks.

For example, I could create a simple script that opens the sound controls (or directly adjust the volume, in the case of ME) at a specific time (or instantly). It is possible to add a parameter in this script that takes the current time and sits idle for an hour, then returns the volume to your desired level.

[image: macro express mute script]

In the image above, visible in the command editor, the Wait for Time to Elapse was set to one hour as per your question. I did not assign a hot key or other activation method to this macro as it is only a test, but one could accomplish activation in many different ways provided by the software.

After having purchased Macro Express (Pro), I discovered a number of late-bloomers which were not available at the time. Some of them were free, but the names have slipped from my alleged mind.

This method could be considered overkill, as was my situation as well, but it has proven valuable in so many other ways since the purchase.